# Filter out product based on options

Tags: arangodb, aql

Am trying to compute a query to filter out products based on filterable options, color, size, e.t.c.

Use case: Obtain all products that have a size 8 and red

**Attempt 1: Using Intersection**

```
FOR product IN products
    FILTER product.options != null

    FOR productOption IN product.options
        FILTER productOption.option == "Size" AND LENGTH( INTERSECTION( productOption.value, ["8","14","16"] ) ) > 0
            AND productOption.option == "Color" AND LENGTH( INTERSECTION( productOption.value, ["Red"] ) ) > 0

RETURN product
```

**Attempt 2: Using Multiple Filters**

```
FOR product IN products
    FILTER product.options != null

    FOR productOption IN product.options
        FILTER productOption.option == "Size"
            FOR productSizeOptionValue IN productOption.value
                FILTER productSizeOptionValue IN ["8","10"]
        FILTER productOption.option == "Color"
            FOR productColorOptionValue IN productOption.value
                FILTER productColorOptionValue IN ["Red"]

RETURN product
```

Am not sure if my thinking should be along the lines of first obtaining possible product candidates using LET than merging the results of each individual LET query. Seemed rather clumsy! :(

Comment: Attempt this http://pastebin.com/hzAsFbuQ, add array index [0] cause I need results as JSON array not [ [ json ] ]. I however don't feel comfortable with implementation. They must be better/more acceptable way...

Answer (score 1):

Attempt 1 will not work because it contains two AND-combined FILTER conditions on `productOption.option`, with different comparison values:

```
...
FILTER 
       productOption.option == "Size" 
   AND LENGTH(INTERSECTION(...))
   AND productOption.option == "Color"
   AND LENGTH(INTERSECTION(...))
...
```

This won't work, because the `option` value cannot be `"Size"` and `"Color"` at the same time.

I think it may be more sensible to model product options as separate attributes instead of using generic option arrays. This will work if a product can only have a single value for each distinct option but not multiple. In this approach, a product would look like this:

```
{ "Size": "8", "Color": "Red", "HasWheels": true }
```

Then filtering on product attributes become easier, e.g.

```
FOR product IN products
  FILTER product.Size IN [ "8", "10" ] 
     AND product.Color == "Red"
  RETURN product
```

Search conditions could then also be OR-combined, e.g.

```
  FILTER product.Size IN [ "8", "10" ] 
      OR product.Color == "Red"
```

This approach will make querying much easier. It comes with one disadvantage though, and that is that if there are many different product attributes, you will not be able to index most of them due to memory constraint. This is not a problem if there are few different product attributes, or if all search conditions use a few common attributes that are selective enough that an index greatly speeds up the lookup.

Comment: Just to clarify, you suggesting I store product variants aka "options" in separate documents to ease indexing and data retrieval? This http://pastebin.com/hzAsFbuQ seems to be working, I haven't tested thoroughly though. Will run additional tests and confirm.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest that. I was suggesting that each product document contains its own options as a flat object. For example, this could be a product with all its options `{ "Size": "8", "Color": "Red", "HasWheels": true }`. This is the same as in your original question with the exception that I did not put the product options into a sub-attribute `options` (which would still work with my approach) and that in my case the product options are not an array but first-class attributes of the document.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately that won't work for current use case, because of complexity in products and how current front-end is built to display product data. i.e. { ..., options:[{...}], specifications:[{...}], features:[{...}] } each attribute can be used in filters to extract specific products that meet filter criteria. I believe it would make sense to store these extra attributes as separate documents so product document doesn't get large and also minding memory constrains.

Comment: What you could probably do is to use a single document per product, and have the three top-level attributes in it as sub-documents like this: `{ ..., "options": { Size: "8", "Color": "Red" }, "specifications": { ... }, "features": { ... } }`. Not sure if that's ruled out because your product definitions are too complex for that, but it may still be worth checking, because it will make querying easy.

Comment: I will investigate that option of storing product data and revert with outcomes. Thanks :)

Comment: Did the Answer fullfill your needs? If, can you please accept it?